# RabbitMQ - Consuming messages from queue in microservices

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I am trying to integrate RabbitMQ as a messaging queue in my existing microservice project. I currently have a `Send` function written which takes a string message and publishes to a named queue.

Now, I am trying to write the `Receive` function and here is what I have so far:

```
public static void Receive(string queueName)
{
    using (IConnection connection = GetConnection(LOCALHOST))
    {
        using (IModel channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            channel.QueueDeclare(queue: queueName, durable: true, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);

            // Don't dispatch a new message to a consumer until it has processed and acknowledged the previous one.
            channel.BasicQos(prefetchSize: 0, prefetchCount: 1, global: false); 

            var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel); // non-blocking

            consumer.Received += (model, e) =>
            {
                var body = ea.Body;
                var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                // At this point, I can do something with the message.
            };

            channel.BasicConsume(queue: queueName, autoAck: true, consumer: consumer);
        }
    }
}
```

I think that is okay but I have a few questions on parts that I am confused on.

1) I don't quite understand what the `Received` field is and why it is appending an anonymous function in which we do the actual work after receiving.

2) What is `BasicConsume` doing? Does the actual receiving happen with `BasicConsume` or the `Received` field? Does `BasicConsume` have to occur after the `Received` field assign?

3) Finally, I have, say, two microservices that need to consume from a queue. I thought that I can just call `Receive` in those two microservices respectively. Will it continually listen for messages or do I need to place the `Receive` call in a while loop?

Thanks for your help and illumination.

Comment: Using MassTransit is a great way to remove the complexity of dealing with Rabbit directly. I'd highly recommend it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) `Received` is actually an event. So, calling `consumer.Received += (model, e) => {};` you're subscribing to it, but it's not necesseraly an anonimous function, it can be like:

```
consumer.Received += OnReceived;

....

private static void OnReceived(object model, BasicDeliverEventArgs e)
{
    var body = ea.Body;
    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
    // At this point, I can do something with the message.
}
```

It is executed each time you recieve a message.

2) `BasicConsume` starts a consumer of your channel, which you created before. The function in Recieved will be executed.

3) They will continually listen the channel in case of using `EventingBasicConsumer`. It may require a loop for another type of `Consumer`